# Trouble with invokeAPI and Custom API in Azure Cordova

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have a javascript Cordova application trying to call a custom API from Azure mobile services.  The code in my Cordova app is as follows:

```
       XXXXServicesClient.invokeApi(
                'getremaining', {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "body": {"alertID": app.existingAlerts[index].id}
               }).done(
            function(results)
            {
                    remaining = results;
            }, function (err) { alert(err) });
```

This is the custom API

```
exports.get = function (request, response) {
//get the table
var idToFind = request.body.alertID;
console.info("line 11");
var XXXXTable = request.service.tables.getTable('XXXXTable');
console.info("line 13");
console.info(idToFind);
console.info("parameter" + request.body.alertID);
response.send(200, idToFind);
};
```

I am getting this error: Error in script '/api/gettimeremaining.js'. TypeError: Cannot read property 'alertID' of undefined at exports.get.  This is referring to this line in the API:

```
var idToFind = request.body.alertID;
```

All other Mobile Services (such as tables) are working fine.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use a HTTP method other than GET To have a request.body property.  Try changing to a POST/PUT/etc method.